# Singleton function not retaining value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'll preface this question by saying that I am a total noob when it comes to Objective-C. So please, be patient with my question. :)

So here is my issue. I am basically allowing the user to 'rub out' an image by using alpha blending and such, and then converting the created texture to a CCSprite. I am then able to store the CCSprite in a function within my singleton class. Like so:

```
erasedTextureSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:darknessLayer.sprite.texture];

[[MySingleton sharedMySingleton] setRevealTexture:erasedTextureSprite];
```

Here is the `setRevealTexture` & `getRevealTexture` function as well as the revealTexture variable initialisation in my `MySingleton.h` file:

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject
{
    CCSprite *revealTexture;
}

...

-(void) setRevealTexture: (CCSprite *) texture;
-(CCSprite *) getRevealTexture;
```

And here are both functions in my `MySingleton.m` file:

```
-(void) setRevealTexture: (CCSprite *) texture
{
    NSLog(@"set reveal texture.");
    revealTexture = texture;
    NSLog(@"%f", [revealTexture boundingBox].size.width);
}

-(CCSprite *) getRevealTexture
{
    NSLog(@"got reveal texture.");
    NSLog(@"%f", revealTexture.contentSize.width);
    return revealTexture;
}
```

If I set the reveal texture, and then get it right away, it seems to return the sprite correctly. However, if I set the texture and then transition to another scene, it seems to lose it's value, and throws me an error when I try and call the `getRevealTexture` function.

***Question***: **Why is my function not retaining it's value when I transition between scenes?**

If any more clarification is needed please let me know!

Comment: Generally one would retain an object by sending a retain message.  I don't see where you are retaining.

Comment: @Sneaksta you need to go look at some introductory info on memory management in objective-c, with specific attention to properties, ARC, and the release/retain cycle.   This will clear things up for you.  Also, it's standard in objective-c for getters to not have a `get` prefix.  That is reserved for a very specific type of method that returns arrays of unsafe values for operations such as fast enumeration.

Comment: Thanks @gaige. I will do some more research. It just seems curious to me as I have other methods with getter and setters that seem to work great (retaining values and all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically there is no point in using your own setter and getter if your not doing anything fancy.
What you are doing is using an iVar which should have been a strong property.

you could achieve the same by doing:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *revealTexture;
```

in your header file.
You would then get the following 2 functions by default:

```
[[MySingleton sharedMySingleton] revealTexture];
[[MySingleton sharedMySingleton] setRevealTexture:texture];
```

My next point of failure that I would presume if this doesn't work is that your singleton function is not working properly and your actually getting a new instance each time.
You can easily find this out by doing in the debugger:

```
po [MySingleton sharedMySingleton]
```

And seeing the instance that is returned each time.

example for a basic singleton code:

```
static MySingleton *__sharedMySingleton = nil;

+ (id)sharedMySingleton {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedMySingleton = [MySingleton new]; // or a specific alloc init function
    });

    return __sharedMySingleton;
}
```

Due to the request - here is a short image to explain how to enter debugger commands in xcode 5:
[image]

Comment: I have searched google but can't seem to find how to enter input into the debugger in Xcode 5?

Comment: Added an image for you to explain how to enter input in the debugger area in xcode 5.

Comment: What a legend! All I was missing was the pausing :)

Comment: would you be free for a chat to help me through some of my issues?

Comment: It turns out I was giving the wrong value to the singleton! I should have been giving it the 'darknessLayer.sprite' property, but instead I was giving it the 'darknessLayer.sprite.texture' property and using it in [CCSprite spriteWithTexture: ...]

Comment: :) Happens to the best of us. at least you picked up a few tricks and practices along the way.